# Image refresh setInterval with Stop Start button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, setinterval

I have an image that is set to refresh every 1000 milliseconds.

```
var int_time = setInterval(function() {
var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
myImageElement.src = 'https://api.evercam.io/v1/cameras/<%= @camera["id"] %>/snapshot.jpg?api_id=<%= current_user.api_id -%>&api_key=<%= current_user.api_key -%>?rand=' + new Date().getTime();
}, 1000);

img.onclick = function() { clearInterval(int_time); }
```

I would like to add a stop /start button that prevents it from refreshing on click and restarts its on click like a play pause button would behave.

Does anyone know how I would achieve this for refreshing images?

Answer (score 0):

Save the return value of setInterval and then use clearInterval to stop the interval when the user clicks

```
var intervalId = setInterval(...);

img.onclick = function() { clearInterval(intervalId); }
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Barroso so should me edited code above work as I can't get it to stop updating the image.

Comment: You should use your image element myImageElement.onclick = function() { ... }

Answer (score 0):

```
var int_time = setInterval(function() {
var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
myImageElement.src = 'https://api.evercam.io/v1/cameras/<%= @camera["id"] %>/snapshot.jpg?        api_id=<%= current_user.api_id -%>&api_key=<%= current_user.api_key -%>?rand=' + new Date().getTime();
}, 1000);
```

Now to stop the interval just call

```
clearInterval(int_time);
```

and to restart the interval again call

```
var int_time = setInterval(function() {
var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
myImageElement.src = 'https://api.evercam.io/v1/cameras/<%= @camera["id"] %>/snapshot.jpg?        api_id=<%= current_user.api_id -%>&api_key=<%= current_user.api_key -%>?rand=' + new Date().getTime();
}, 1000);
```